# SlideUp or Animate When With Bound Events

Tags: jquery, menu, bind

In the below example, I am curious how i could still use slide up and slidedown to animate the ul for appearing. My confusion is meant by, slideUp/slideDown are display none, and it seems like in this example thy are using another css property, visibility. On the function jsddm_open, i would like for the UL to slide in and slide out. Thanks for your time.

```
var timeout    = 500;
var closetimer = 0;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function jsddm_open()
{  jsddm_canceltimer();
   jsddm_close();
   dmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');

}

function jsddm_close()
{  if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');}

function jsddm_timer()
{  closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);}

function jsddm_canceltimer()
{  if(closetimer)
   {  window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
      closetimer = null;}}

$(document).ready(function(){  

$('#menudropdown > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open)
   $('#menudropdown > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer)

});

document.onclick = jsddm_close;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the jquery function .slideToggle():

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

This will allow you to animate your elements without necessarily having to check their current state of visibility.

EDIT

It's possible to assign a selector as a variable and pass it between functions.

```
function jsddm_open()
{  
   var current_element = $(this);
   jsddm_canceltimer();   
   jsddm_close(current_element);

   $("ul", this).slideDown();
}

function jsddm_close(current_element)
{  
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('display', 'none'){
      current_element.slideUp();}

;}
```

Comment: i had tried typing    $("ul", this).slideUp(); or    $("ul", this).slideDown(); but failed, as soon as i tried:    $("ul", this).slideToggle(); everything worked fine.

Comment: the reason why i am a local idiot is because, in my css, that i failed to attach, the visibility was set to hidden. I removed the reference in the css to the visibility property and set the display property to none. this allowed my usage of slide up and slideDown.

Comment: i am almost there. however im not sure how to pass the (this) to another function, to close the correct UL. i have modified my question.